# как распарсить очень большой текстовый файл с использованием регулярного выражения?

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, python-3.x, pandas

Добрый день! У меня есть файл в формате txt на ~3,5 млн. строк. Большинство строк примерно такого вида:

> Иванов Иван Иванович 12.02.1942 675195, Москва, ул. Ивановых, дом 15,
>   4512 125345 выдан Орденом Ивановых 11.11.2011.

Соответственно, я пытаюсь записать строки в DataFrame и разбить на столбцы по регулярному выражению таким кодом:

```
#Входной и выходной файлы
file = 'file.txt'
out = 'file1.txt'

#Чтение файла и запись в список
data = []
with open(file) as read_file:
    for line in read_file:
        data.append(line.strip())
read_file.close()

#Создание фрейма
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name' : data})

#Регулярка, проверенная на regex101.com
rx = '(?P<Name>.*?)\s+(?P<Date>\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4})\s+(?P<Adress>.*)\s+(?P<Passport>\d{4}\s+.*)'

#Запись во фрейм
df = df.Name.str.extract(rx, expand=True)
```

В результате этого кода Python уходит в задумчивость из которой больше не возвращается.

Функуция timeit дает тот же эффект - задумчивость.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как быть?

**UPDATE:**
Решил разбить строки по сериям, которые складываются во фрейм таким образом и все получилось как надо:

```
#Регулярные выржаения для разделителей
rxName = '(?P<Name>[а-яАЁ-ёя\s]*)'
rxDate = '(?P<Date>\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{4})'
rxAdress = '(?P<Adress>\d*,\s\D*\s\d*)'
rxPassport = '(?P<Passport>\d{4}\s\D\d{6}\s.*\s\\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{4})$'

#Процедура разделения по столбцам
df['Name'] = df.Name.str.extract(rxName, expand=False)
df['Date'] = df.Name.str.extract(rxDate, expand=False)
df['Adress'] = df.Name.str.extract(rxAdress, expand=False)
df['Passport'] = df.Name.str.extract(rxPassport, expand=False)
```

Похоже что в задумчивость Python вводили некоторые строки, которые сильно не соответствовали шаблону и поэтому он не понимал в какую группу их отнести.

Решение конечно не идеальное, наверняка есть и получше, но работает.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59806/discussion-on-question-by-denis-novik------).

Comment: В общем случае (без pandas), можно mmap использовать, чтобы применить регулярное выражение к файлу ([пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/693448/23044))

Comment: А что собственно с этими строками вы хотите делать? Отсортировать, отфильтровать, что-то проанализировать? У вас оперативной памяти сколько? Хватает для всего считывания данных? Вот полезная статья - https://www.quora.com/Can-Python-Pandas-handle-10-million-rows-What-are-some-useful-techniques-to-work-with-the-large-data-frames

Answer (score 1):

При разделении строк в файлах большого объема с использованием регулярного выражения имеет смысл разделять строку отдельно по группам и затем собирать полученнные серии в датафрейм.